# Double arithmetic giving false result

Tags: c++, gnu, arithmetic-expressions

I don't know why this code below is giving me "no". I tried to cast -0.2 to double and still getting "no"? What is the problem and how to fix it?

```
double d = -4;

double d1= -4.2;

if (d1== (d-0.2))
    cout<< "yes"<<endl;
else
    cout <<"no"<<endl;
```

Comment: [What every developer needs to know about floating point](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: http://www.smbc-comics.com/index.php?db=comics&id=2999#comic ([Not mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken))

Comment: I don't see the rounding error though: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/95f99c83bab5e5b5

Comment: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/floating-point-arith.html

Comment: N-hundredth duplicate about "floating-point math broken" on SO

Comment: Ok, thank you all , didn't know that it was floating problem.